# Error parsing HTTP resposne while using "requests" python library

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to parse a list of HTML pages for IP addresses listed on those pages.
Initially my code worked fine where I was calling the `requests()` params inside my `parse_ip()` function.
As the functionality expanded, I decided to take the HTTP connection part into a separate `connect()` function and then later call it inside the parse function. 
But ever since I did that, my parsing is not not returning any results, 
Even though I am searching for an IP address that is listed in one of the HTML pages in my list.

Here is my code snippet:

```
def connect():
    for filename, source in threat.iteritems():
        sessions = requests.Session()
        print "Now connecting with", source
        r = sessions.get(source,
                         headers = create_basic_headers(),
                         proxies = {'http': HTTP_PROXY, 'https': HTTPS_PROXY})
def parse(ip):
    counter = 0
    ioc_list = []
    r = connect()
    while r != None:
        for line in r:
            if line.startswith("/") or line.startswith('\n') or line.startswith("#"):
                pass
            else:
                if ip in line:
                    ioc_list.append(ip)
                    print ioc_list
                    counter += 1
```

Can anyone kindly point where I am going wrong. 
`def parse(ip)`, here ip is passed as argument .

*****Edit****

as per the comment, I added return to the connect() function. 
The loop is now able to parse the HTML pages for input argument, but I am encountering a variable problem. Here is my modified code:

```
def connect():
    for filename, source in threat.iteritems():
        sessions = requests.Session()
        print "Now connecting with", source
        try:
            r = sessions.get(source,
                            headers = create_basic_headers(),
                            proxies = {'http': HTTP_PROXY, 'https': HTTPS_PROXY})
            return r
        except:
            sys.stdout.write('[!] Could not connect to: %s\n' % source)


def parse(ip):
    counter = 0
    ioc_list = []
    r = connect()
    while r != None:
        for line in r:
            if line.startswith("/") or line.startswith('\n') or line.startswith("#"):
                pass
            else:
                if ip in line:
                     ioc_list.append(ip)
                     print ioc_list, source
                     counter += 1
```

This results in following error:

> line 55, in parse_ip
>       print ioc_list, source NameError: global name 'source' is not defined

Any ideas on fixing this ?

Comment: You aren't returning anything from `connect`. So the `r` value in  `parse` will always be `None`. Plus your while loop is redundant. It would only make sense to do that if you expected `r` to change between loop iterations.

Comment: thanks solved the problem, but stuck with another.. updated my question :)

Comment: There's a few things wrong with your code. How can you expect `source` a variable private to the function `connect` be seen by `parse`? Also consider what is `connect` supposed to do. Presently it just connects to the first source it can then returns the requests object. Did you want to loop through all sources in your dict `threat`? If so you might wish to return a list of the connections or use a generator function. Lastly you might consider using the same requests `Session` for all connections, instead of creating a new one for each connection.

Answer (score 0):

You've added another argument to the print statement at the second-from-bottom line of your code you posted:

```
print ioc_list, source
```

There is no variable in scope named `source` at that line, so that is the error that you are getting.  You most likely don't want to be printing out the contents of the list every iteration through that loop either - did you mean to instead use

```
print ip
```

Comment: I plan to print the name of the HTML source which had a succesfull hit. So ip_list or ip would print the matching IP and source would be the page parsed.. 'source' is passed on from another .py file into connect() function..'r = sessions.get(source,
                            headers = create_basic_headers(),
                            proxies = {'http': HTTP_PROXY, 'https': HTTPS_PROXY})'